# Parse to object with a route like ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC it's possible to define a route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute("myroute",
    "myroute/{country}/{name}-{type}",
    new { controller = "MyController", action = "Get" });
```

And that would parse it directly to an object:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
   public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromRoute] MyViewModel model)
   {
      //TODO do stuff with model.
   }
}
```

This is my view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type{ get; set; }
}
```

My question is, can I do the same parsing in a simple console app?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string route = "myroute/{country}/{name}-{type}";

        string input = "myroute/Denmark/MyName-MyType";

        //TODO Parse input to MyViewModel with route
        MyViewModel result;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

There must be some way of doing this, since it's possible for ASP.NET MVC routing.

Comment: There definitely is a way to do this, write some code to parse your values and set them with `PropertyInfo`, just give it a try, there is a lot of stuff on that, start with regex or split

Comment: I don't know if there's an in-built way. I'd be tempted to convert the route to regex (you can automate this), and then you can test the "url" against the generated regex. If you take the names in `{` `}` to name your regex groups, you can also easily extract the data.

Comment: Not going to use split, that would make it impossible to change the route to something else.

Comment: Some regex would might work, just not sure how to parse to an object with that.

And when its possible for asp.net mvc rounting, it must be possible to do the same with an simple string.

Comment: Lets see if someone can make a nicer solution, but its a start :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Parsing and applying the route template is actually pretty simple using [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing):

```
string route = "/myroute/{country}/{name}-{type}";
string input = "/myroute/Denmark/MyName-MyType";

var routeTemplate = TemplateParser.Parse(route);
var matcher = new TemplateMatcher(routeTemplate, null);
var values = new RouteValueDictionary();

if (matcher.TryMatch(input, values))
{
    foreach (var item in values)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", item.Key, item.Value);
    }
}
```

```
country: Denmark
type: MyType
name: MyName
```

However, binding that to an entity would mean that you will have the whole [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) stack which happens to be a “bit” more complex to spin up separately. So instead, I would just recommend you to make this manually using a little bit of reflection:

```
public static T BindValues<T>(RouteValueDictionary values)
    where T : new()
{
    var obj = new T();
    foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
    {
        if (values.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, values[prop.Name]);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And used like this:

```
var obj = BindValues<MyViewModel>(values);
```

While this is obviously a lot less powerful than model binding, it should work fine enough for your use case.